# Windows 7 virtual PC - use main graphics card

Tags: windows, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode, windows-7

I have installed virtual pc to run XP inside of windows 7 professional. When I run "dxdiag" and go to the display tab on 7 I can see my graphics card details (ATI Radeon etc) but when I run it in the XP mode it says N/A and doesn't support anything that my graphics card does such as directdraw, direct3d etc.

Is there a way to get XP to run off my graphics card as I have a game I want to play that only runs in XP and requires direct3d (or maybe some other software?).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the game, as a long shot you can check for updates and/or try to find out if anyone else has got it to work - there are some pretty inventive people out there and you may be surprised.

Apart from that, Virtual PC is not really that good at graphics. You can try [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) which has much much better 3D support, and if you choose not to buy it, simply use [VMWare Player](https://vmware.com/products/player/) when the trial is over.

Comment: Thanks Wil, why do I need to use workstation then player if player is free? Can I not just install player and go?

Comment: Of course you can. VMWare enabled creating guests in Player also just recently.

Comment: Simply put, VMWare Player works well and is free - but, VMWare Workstation is like the enterprise version - so many extra features and just brilliant. Not needed but if you have never used it, I would always recommend it... but the main reason was I didn't know that Vmware Player let you create them +1 to @Shiki

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. VMWare supports 3D inside VMs, almost perfectly. It's close to perfect. VirtualBox also supports it, actually its a Wine hack/ripoff, and it's the worst. It's really just for show-off and it's considered to be an experimental feature (it won't let you install it that easily.)

Request a 30day trial from VMWare or get the VMWare player, that also supports it as far as I know.

Comment: »it won't let you install it that easily« – takes a single checkbox to enable here.

Comment: Well. And you have to boot into Recovery mode, etc etc to get proper acceleration set up. It is not that straightforward NOR supported NOR really working.

Answer (score 1):

WinXP mode emulates an old crappy graphic card. It is a better option to innstall a real WinXP version in addition to windows7.