# Windows XP Mode on Win7 - graphics card S3 trio 32/64 problem

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, windows-xp-mode

I have a new laptop with **Windows 7 x64 ULTI** on it.
I installed the **Windows XP mode**, everything runs ok.

The problem is that the XP machine supports only this virtual graphics driver, which is not enough for some graphical applications like games:

```
MS Integration components S3 trio 32/64
```

The piece of HW I own is is Radeon 5870 mobile.
S3 supports only the basic resolution mode 640*480 and the old games won't run on it unless I install some better graphics.
How could I replace the S3 graphics my my real one? and with my real ATI drivers?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably the games in question cannot run in Win7 proper? Even with all the relevant compatibility options? How "old" are we talking with these games?

Comment: Also, this is a close duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/164952/windows-7-virtual-pc-use-main-graphics-card and offers a few answers.

Comment: Well the problem is not that I couldnt get running it under Windows 7, I still have DOSBOX and other possibilites. The problem is that some of them are freezing in that way I am not able to do anything in the OS. This is not the issue under WinXP. That's why I decided to run all of them under the VM and WinXP.

Comment: Fair enough. In which case I think the direct answer is "no", because MS Virtual PC doesn't support showing the real hardware AFAIK. The linked question advises try VM Ware Player, which apparent does support this.

Comment: I cant understand your question clearly can you modify your question, the real one (not the comment)

Comment: hope it's clear now :)